# How do you enable NTFS compression across all drives?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs, compression

How do I enable NTFS compression for each of my drives?

Currently it is available on my C: NVMe, E: SATA SSD, and my K: HDD
but the drives I actually want to compress are not able.

K: drive able to be compressed
[image: K: drive able to be compressed]

R: Drive unable to be compressed
[image: R: Drive unable to be compressed]

The K drive is actually located in the same bay as my R: and I: drives, but the compression options are different.

I've made all the basic changes most sites say about the group policy editor, the regedit item, and the Fsutil in CMD.

I don't understand why the outcomes seem to be varied by drive and not homogenous across the system.

Requested Drive info:

C: is a WD Black SN850X 4tb 4096 bytes per Cluster - can compress

E: is a Samsung MZ7TE512HMHP-000L2 512GB - 2048 bytes - can compress

I: is an external drive, most likely a seagate barracuda, 6TB - 2097152 bytes per cluster  - wont compress

K: 12tb Ironwolf Pro also in DAS - 4096B - Can compress

R: Is RAID 1 12TB Drives - 2097152B per cluster - wont compress

All disks had been formatted locally on this machine.

Obviously the issue is that I had formatted to a much larger cluster size on these drives which does not support NTFS compression.

It was several years ago but I think the idea with increasing my allocation unit size was to make it more efficient because my main file type was large video files.

Comment: NTFS is a folesydtem. It xant compress devices or other filesystems (ie it cant operste on FAT formatted partitions)

Comment: Hey I don't know why comments are gone I didn't try to delete them. 
I know it cannot compress exfat which is why I didn't list any other relevent details to it. 
I will update with cluster size rather than sector size, sorry I confused the two.

Comment: @badb0ii - Community users are encouraged to flag unnecessary comments, if you have helpful information, it should be in the question body not a comment. When editing a question it’s unnecessary to indicate an edit has happened. It’s also unnecessary to direct commentary within the body of a question to specific users.

Answer (score 2):

NTFS supports compression only at cluster sizes up to 4096 bytes. With your clarification, it is now clear that the non-compressible volumes have cluster sizes larger than 4096 bytes.

This information is somewhat hidden. It is mentioned on Wikipedia, but also on [this Microsoft KB article on default cluster sizes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat-9772e6f1-e31a-00d7-e18f-73169155af95#ID0EFD):

> By default, the maximum cluster size for NTFS under Windows NT 4.0 and later versions of Windows is 4 kilobytes (KB). This is because NTFS file compression is not possible on drives that have a larger cluster size.

You may have inadvertently selected a larger cluster size when formatting the drive.

Unfortunately, this problem cannot be solved without re-formatting the volumes in question.

Comment: Depending on the drives themselves they also might be natively 4K, most larger mechanical drives, natively use 4k sectors